# hover effect jumps when mouse leaves

Tags: css, hover

I created a hovereffect. First I hide a div on hover. Second I scale an image smaller and third I move the content below the image up. This is working, I did it with tansitions. To make the effect a bit more beautiful I addded this:

transition: transform .4s,-webkit-transform .4s;

When my mouse leaves this widget there is a little jump and I cannot find out the reason for this.

```css
.nuss_widget {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 height: 530px;
}

.nuss_widget .hover {
 transition: transform .4s,-webkit-transform .4s;
}

.nuss_widget .image img {
 max-width: 200px;
 height: auto;
}
.nuss_widget:hover .image img {
 transform: scale(.6,.6);
 transform-origin: top;
}

.nuss_widget .meta {
 display: block;
}
.nuss_widget:hover .meta {
 display: none;
}

.nuss_widget:hover .hover_top {
 transform: translateY(-90px);
}

.nuss_widget .hover.fade_up {
 display: none;
}
.nuss_widget:hover .hover.fade_up {
 display: block;
}

.bottom {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nuss_widget">
  <div class="hover meta">
    <span>Kostenlos</span>
    <span>Sofort verfügbar</span>
  </div>

  <div class="hover image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x240" class="hover">
  </div>
  <div class="hover hover_top">
    <p class="topline">topline</p>
    <h2>titel</h2>
    <p class="hover fade_up description">
      paar Zeilen Text<br>paar Zeilen Text<br>paar Zeilen Text<br>paar Zeilen Text<br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <p class="price">
      <span class="old_price">10,00 €</span>
      <span class="current_price">8,00 €</span>
    </p>
    <a href="#" class="button">Details ansehen</a>
    <div class="price_meta">
      <p>Preis inkl. 20% Mwst. <a href="">zzgl. Versand</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- /nuss_widget -->
```

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: What do you mean with "jump"? Does it lag due to too massive CSS calculations? It doesn't jump on my Mac Pro with Firefox, given that you don't mean the div that disappears to everything jumps up. Try changing the animation to 6s to clearly debug the problem.

Comment: Move    transform-origin: top;     to the .nuss_widget .image img   selector and remove it from    .nuss_widget:hover .image img.  That should solve it :)

Comment: Thank you Rickard, I changed the animation to 6s and moved the transform-origin. It is much more better, but there is still a little jump. This doesn't happen when I remove this part:

.nuss_widget .meta {
 display: block;
}
.nuss_widget:hover .meta {
 display: none;
}

It seems to me that transform doesn't work on this, but I can't understand why :/